# Play a song in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I was trying to play a song in iOS, but it gives me an error message.

#### HEADER FILE .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface PRPViewController : UIViewController{
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    IBOutlet UIButton *start;
}

-(IBAction)play;

@end
```

#### IMPLEMENTATION FILE .m

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/bobmarley.mp3",          
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsofURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

[audioPlayer play];
```

#### but it says

> No visible @interface for AVAudioPlayer declares the selector 'initWithContentsofUrl:error:'

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the file is available on your system with the method `initWithContentsOfURL`, yours is written wrong. Otherwise the app can crash. I created a class which handles everything for me:

```
@implementation AudioPlayer{

    AVAudioPlayer *_sound;
    NSURL *_soundURL;
    NSString *_receivedValue;

    float _volumeSpecific;
}

- (id)initWithAudioFile:(NSString *)fileName andExtension:(NSString *)extension{

    self = [super init];
    if( self ){
        _receivedValue = fileName;

        _soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName
                                                     ofType:extension]];
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[_soundURL path]]){
            _sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_soundURL 
                                                            error:nil];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)playEndless{

    if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kSound] ){
        _sound.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [_sound play];
    }
}

- (void)setVolume:(float)myVolume{

    _volumeSpecific = myVolume;
    [_sound setVolume:myVolume];
}

- (void)play{
    if( _sound == nil ){
        NSLog(@"No AudioPlayer available %@", self);
    }
    if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kSound] ){

        if( _volumeSpecific ){
            [_sound setVolume:_volumeSpecific];
        }
        [_sound play];
    }
}

- (NSString *)description{        
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Received: %@, Player: %@, URL: %@",
            _receivedValue, _sound, _soundURL];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should capitalize the "O" in `Of`. In Objective-C, spelling counts, including capitalization. `initWithContentsofURL` and `initWithContentsOfURL` are two different things.

(By the way, this is a very good reason for using autocompletion as much as possible. The autocompletion mechanism knows much better than you do how to spell the names of the declared methods!)